# Twitter Bootstrap's carousel does not stretch width-wise on the iPhone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter's Bootstrap framework. So please pardon my ignorance.

I am attempting to create a carousel, that is working as expected. However, only on the iPhone it doesn't stretch width-wise. On the computer and iPad it does. Twitter's example ([here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html)) does stretch. Here's a picture.

[image: carousel-width]

Here's my css:

```
/* Carousel base class */

.carousel
{
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.carousel .container 
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.carousel-control 
{
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item 
{
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel img 
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.carousel-caption 
{
  background-color: transparent;
  position: static;
  max-width: 550px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 290px;
}

.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead 
{
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.carousel-caption .btn 
{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you added all required javascript files and jQuery References?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on this page : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

to view Page Source.

navigate to the end and you see this code:

```
  <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script>
      !function ($) {
        $(function(){
          // carousel demo
          $('#myCarousel').carousel()
        })
      }(window.jQuery)
    </script>
    <script src="../assets/js/holder/holder.js"></script>
```

make sure you have this code on your page and links to javascript are right.

If you have added these references then another thing I noticed you use `max-width:` don't use "px" in `max-width:` use "%"

Comment: Bootstrap now only includes `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`. I've added those files. I added the `px` width so that the images are not stretched beyond their max width.

Comment: you also have to add the above mentioned files, for the above features to be included in the website.

Comment: bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js are suppose to be added at start of html file in <head>, these others should be added at the end